# Android mvvm команды из view

Tags: android, mvvm

Почему в MVVM View не должно говорить ViewModel что делать?

Т.е. почему во view не должно быть такого, viewModel.loadData() или viewModel.updateData или viewModel.setName()

А принято public методы viewModel именовать примерно следующим образом:

fun nameChanged(name: String)
fun updateDataRequested()
А внутри уже ViewModel решает как на это реагировать..

Может есть статьи где это объясняется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача View - показывать пользователю состояние приложения, а так же сообщать приложению о действиях пользователя, то есть обрабатывать пользовательский ввод.

Задача View Model - предоставить View данные, к которым View может обращаться и команды, которые View может вызывать. Так же View Model сообщает View, когда данные изменились, чтобы последняя оперативно отобразила эти изменения пользователю.

Задача Model - принимать и отправлять данные.

> Т.е. почему во view не должно быть такого, viewModel.loadData() или viewModel.updateData или viewModel.setName()?

Ну почему же не должно? Представим что `loadData()` - команда, некое свойство вьюмодели `loadDataCommand`, которое содержит внутри себя метод `execute()`. Вы объявляете во View вызов этой команды, скажем при нажатии на кнопку. При этом View не знает, что произойдет когда команда выполнится, она просто делает вызов, и всё. Дальше уже View Model сама изменяет свои данные и сообщает интерфейсу где что поменялось.

И здесь материализуется четкая грань в характерах задач, которые решают View и View Model, с которых я начал писать ответ.

View знает, где у вьюмодели какие свойства, знает где команды, но она ничего не знает о том, что делают эти команды, и когда обновляются свойства, она подписалась на события вьюмодели и ждёт.

Что это нам дает:

1. Можно перепилить или заменить View полностью, оставляя вьюмодель неизменной.
2. Универсальность View Model. Грубо говоря у меня в C#/.NET может быть 3 приложения: WPF, Xamarin и Avalonia, использующие общую библиотеку с вьюмоделями.
3. Изменение Model не влияет на View. Например вчера я использовал XML-RPC API, сегодня сервер новый, и я использую JSON REST API. Model я переписал, в View и View Model трогать не пришлось (а у меня 3 разных вьюхи, помните?).

Подводя итог, скажу что разделение приложения на 3 слоя: представление (View), бизнес-логика (View-Model) и связь с данными (Model) - делает разработку практически любого приложения в 3 раза проще. И чем слабже эти слои связаны - тем удобнее приложение дорабатывать.

Вы сталкивались с ситуацией, когда изменение кода в одном классе влечёт за собой изменения еще в 3 местах приложения? А потом на тестах выясняется, что мест было не 3, а 5, и вы идёте фиксить баги. Именно поэтому и придуманы все эти шаблоны проектирования - облегчить жизнь разработчику.

А чтобы было легче понимать, как организовать объектную модель приложения и окончательно подружиться с тремя принципами ООП - еще придуманы принципы SOLID, которые являются прекрасным дополнением к основным шаблонам проектирования, например к MVVM.

Comment: Ну почему же не должно? - а как же тот момент, что View должно только уведомлять о событиях во View, а не говорить, что с этим делать. т.е. кликнули обновить, мы должны сообщить что произошел какой то пользовательский ввод, например, updateClicked() или updateRequested(), а не жесткий указ update(). ?

Comment: @ripple в разных языках по-разному к этому подходят. Я пишу на шарпе, и у меня SaveFileCommand сохраняет файл, это считается нормальным. У вас в силу других технологий могут быть предложены другие правила именования. Но это не касается MVVM. Называйте методы и свойства как хотите, шаблон это не регламентирует.

Comment: @ripple так, стоп, View ни о каких событиях не уведомляет. Она вызывает команды - конкретные методы или делегаты вьюмодели. Подписка на события View внутри View - это не MVVM, это своя внутренняя логика View.

Comment: ага, я про вызов методов и говорю, я больше о нейминге методов которые вызывает VIEW, например, когда пользователь кликает сохранить файл, вместо vm.saveFileCommand() выполнять vm.saveFileClicked() или vm.saveFileRequested() т.е. View не говорит, что делать, а говорит, что "пользователь захотел сохранить файл, что будешь с этим делать?" ))

Comment: @ripple я за saveFileCommand, так как saveFileClicked это больше похоже на шаблон Publicher/Subscriber. В MVVM вьюмодель не должна знать, что там нажато во View, кнопка, меню и т.д. saveFileCommand и saveFileRequested, как по мне - так одно и то же. А вот saveFileClicked уже выглядит подозрительно, потому что эту опасную идею можно развить в saveFileButtonClicked и saveFileMenuItemClicked/Tapped, и т.д., а ViewModel не должна знать ничего, что там физически происходит во View. Поэтому я бы избегал всяких Clicked.

Comment: с ...Clicked я полностью согласен. Но все таки разница между saveFileRequested и saveFileCommand мне кажется есть) saveFileCommand - как будто View явно настаивает на сохранении(управляет вьюмоделью, так выглядит по неймингу метода), а saveFileRequested просит это сделать, а VM потом решает.  p.s. Спасибо за диалог!)

Comment: @ripple так и есть, View управляет вьюмоделью. Не вижу в этом ничего позорного. View знает команды и у меет их дергать, View не знает, что эти команды делают. То есть например команда не может возвращать значение, никогда. Либо после вызова команды View сама начинает обновлять свои свойства из каких-то свойств вьюмодели - это нарушение MVVM. Обновление интерфейса должно происходить тогда, и только тогда, когда View Model об этом сообщит. Если все ок, то как хотите называйте свои команды, это не нарушает MVVM. Главное - чтобы вы потом в этих названиях сами не запутались.